# Adjust loss for values prediction with difference ranges

Tags: forecasting

how do you deal with loss where the goal is to predict sales on different ranges.

Let's say i have 2 products ( 1 with a sale of 100 and the other one with a sale of 10000 per day ). Is there a way to balance between the difference between the real values and the predictions?

If we predict 50 sales for the first product and 9500 for the last one, we have a loss of 5500, but the first product has an error of 50%
but if we predict 80 for the first product and 9000 for the last one, even if the loss is higher, predictions are equally close to the real values.

any ideas? Thanks in advance